# "Don't take my water, it is …" after touching the bottle with my mouth when I'm ill

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When I drink water, there are two ways to drink. Either I can touch my mouth to the bottle or keep the bottle away from my mouth.

Suppose my friend comes and asks me for water. As I am suffering from fever, I want to say to him: "Don't take my water, it is …". What should I fill there?

I was thinking to use "used" there. But "used" can be used in the case when I didn't touch water with my mouth. So, what should I use? I am not getting the proper word for it.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, you could rephrase: "Oh, you don't want to drink that.  I'm sick and I was drinking from it."

Comment: Forget about illness. If I am not ill and want to tell him that I had drunk water using my mouth. Then how should I say this to him in simple and short manner?

Comment: In that case I'd just say "I've drunk from that". Most people touch bottles with their mouths when drinking from them so it would be assumed that's the method you used unless you specifically said that you poured it into your mouth from above.

Comment: Extremely similar question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192371/how-do-i-politely-say-i-have-used-my-mouth-while-drinking-water-from-a-bottle

Comment: @oerkelens - You're right; mea culpa. I had erroneously thought your link pointed back to the earlier questionf from today. My apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Contaminated" is a common term used to describe something that has been in contact with dangerous organisms or substances and would pass them on. It is most likely what you are after.

"Tainted" is also used in this case, but is less formal and slightly less precise (it could be tainted with something distasteful, but not harmful).

"Adulterated" is the term used in technical and legal communication (FDA reports).

To answer your second question (comment), I do not think there is a single specific word in English to describe "risky-because-of-having-been-drunk-out-of". You would have to say, as snailplane suggests, "I drank out of that". The fact that you touched the water would be implied, because you wouldn't warn them if you had not.

Comment: Okay! now imagine that I am not ill, then? I just want to say him that I had drunk water using my mouth touched to it. So, how should I say this? Forget about illness and all.

Comment: You can say, "You don't want that bottle, it's got my germs[cooties] on it." or jokingly, "No, we're not quite to that point in our relationship."

Comment: I don't know of a specific word in my dialect of American English.  "Contaminated" is an awfully clinical term, and rather strong to apply to a bottle with a bit of saliva on it.

Comment: @swbarnes2 In my British English dialect, you could say "contaminated" but it would be a bit jokey, because, as you pointed out, it's a bit strong to use just for a bottle you've drunk from when ill.

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker, I wonder: is the problem with the water, or with the bottle?

That said, a few expressions come to mind. The first one is the most direct:

> You might not want to drink from that bottle; **Ann already had her mouth on it**.

The second is more of a euphemism than a scientific fact:

> Don't drink from that bottle – **it has germs**.

(We don't know for a fact that the water has any contaminants, but the word *germs* is often used to refer to unseen microorganisms that could spread disease, particularly in informal speech.)

Because the concern is mainly with someone else drinking from the bottle, you could also say:

> Be careful! That may have someone's **backwash** in it.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backwash) labels this definition of *backwash* as "informal", while the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=backwash) says:

> *Backwash is often created inadvertently or unintentionally when liquid escapes the mouth during the process of drinking .. When multiple people drink from the same container, there will usually be some amount of backwash put back into the container*.

As a footnote, the adjective for drinkable water is *potable*, though anyone who would deem bottled water as non-potable simply because someone else drank from the bottle is probably using extreme hyperbole, or else is an overly sensative [germaphobe](http://www.yourdictionary.com/germaphobe).

Comment: Excellent! :) Especially for the first sentence quoted and the word *backwash*. Wow! :)

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the bottle. The person who used bottle is not sick. This is a great answer.

Comment: Note that the comment by RuchirM was made when I had answered a [different question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46215/dont-drink-from-this-bottle), before I knew this was a duplicate. (Thanks to @oerkelens for the helpful tip!)

Comment: My question has no connection with illness. The person who drinks is perfectly okay. It's more about manners than contamination or germs. I don't agree with this merge as a moderator you can delete my original question, because this misguides me.

Comment: Agreed! @RuchirM it is *now* entirely different! :(

Comment: This *was* indeed an excellent answer but ***now,*** for this question (after merging it), it's *quite* irrelevant. Want to retract my vote; it's not allowing though.

Comment: @Maulik - Entirely different? Quite irrelevant? I think you're overstating things. The original question asked about 'spoiled' water, or 'used' water - does it really matter if the person is ill or not? The issue in _both_ questions is our aversion to drinking something that someone else may have drank from, and how to describe the water (or the water bottle) in that situation.

Comment: @RuchirM - I don't see the need to have two questions, one for when the person is ill, and the other for when the person is sick. My answer would be the same for both questions, but if the merge bothers you that much, you are free to delete your question and lose the rep you gained from it.

Comment: you are taking it *medically* again. I **know** this being a doctor and *Indian.* Do you know just like bottle, we have a ***noun*** for 'food' as well which is *eaten* by someone else? Ruchir, being an Indian (I guess), is asking for *that* word. Suppose I am eating [khichdi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khichdi) with hand in a plate and ate a very little portion of it. If Ruchir comes (he's my best friend and thus does not need permission to ask for food) and takes my plate, you may stop him.... Hey, don't take that plate, it's **[we have a word here]**. The ***same*** goes with bottle etc.

Comment: @MaulikV Exactly. I am looking for a word "Jhootha".

Comment: @RuchirM  Yes...I had a hint of that. J.R's answer 'someone already had their mouth on it' is **the answer** for bottle/water. However, for food, *jootha khana (Hindi)*, I'm afraid, there's no word in English! Maybe, the safest way is... that's Ruchir's plate... works.

Comment: J.R. to keep this site useful, I would like to delete my question. Especially for Indians, it is misleading (your first sentence is the answer as Maulik V says but then germs and all -'jootha khana (eating) /peena (drinking)' has no connection. Indians will understand this. So, how do I delete it?

Comment: @MaulikV - No, I'm not "taking it medically again." I made a decision based on incomplete information. Had the information you provided in your comment been in the original question, the original question would not have been flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @RuchirM - I've reopened your question and moved my answer back over there. You may want to add a few more details to your question, so that non-Indians can more plainly see how your question and this question are not duplicates.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I'll edit the question the way I understand it. And the OP also seems to agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no single English word that means "my lips have touched this drinking container". You would have to use a descriptive sentence or phrase, like "I drank from this" or "I had my lips on this" or, particularly if you had been sick, "This has my germs on it", etc.